# physics objects collisions not very accurate

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics, scenekit, scnnode

Hello I have a SceneKit game and I would like two objects to collide and physically react to the other. This works fine on all objects except one. This shape seems to be inaccurate as my player (a rolling ball) will often pass right through a portion of it while other times it will react to the collision. I think it may have to do with the speed of the ball. Is there a way to increase the accuracy of this object? Thanks

```
let PillarGeometry = SCNCylinder(radius: 3, height: 3)
        PillarGeometry.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        let Pillar = SCNNode(geometry: PillarGeometry)
        Pillar.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Static, shape: nil)
        Pillar.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionByStanderCategory
        Pillar.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionBallCategory
        Pillar.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 3, 0)
        Pillar.categoryBitMask = colorCategory
        Box.addChildNode(Pillar)
```

Comment: In Sprite Kit there's a physics body property "precise collision detection". Pretty sure there's something like that for Scene Kit as well. Check the class reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can increase the scene's `physicsWorld.timeStep` to a smaller value, e.g. 1/300.